# Numerical solution of non-linear differential equation with MATLAB

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, approximation, matlab

I need some information to know if I can solve a nonlinear integral equation with terms

$ u_{x} $  , $ u_{x}.u_{y} $ , $ u_{xx} $ , $ u_{xy} $ $u_{yy} $ $ u_{x}^{2} $ $ u_{y} ^{2} $

By numerical methods using MATLAB

Also how I introduce in MATLAB the boundary conditions? For example for a minimal surface in 3-D thanks

Comment: I assume that you mean *partial differential equation* (PDE). Do you have the [Partial Differential Equation Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/pde/index.html) for Matlab? Type `ver pde` in your command window if you don't know.

Answer (score 0):

A minimal surface problem is an Elliptic PDE. [MATLAB's documentation has an example for how to solve this here](http://it.mathworks.com/help/pde/ug/pdenonlin.html).